# How to access variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 var a=[1,2,3];
 var b=a;
 b.push(4,5);
 console.log(b);
 console.log(a);
```

I want a value as [1,2,3]. But it printing [1,2,3,4,5] How can I achieve this. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: `I want a value [1,2,3]` for what? b? a? both? something else?

Comment: I want to use a value is [1,2,3] and b value is [1,2,3,4,5]. But I am getting a value is [1,2,3,4,5].

Comment: Since array work on call by reference[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value], so you have to use concat method to solve your problem , because concat method create a new array which didn't modify existing array.  Solution:  var a =[1,2,3];  b = [].concat(a); b.push(4,5); console.log(b); console.log(a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the array's object reference to another one variable. But here what you want to do is to copy the array to create a new instance.

```
 var a=[1,2,3];
 var b= a.slice(0);
 b.push(4,5);

 console.log(b); //[1,2,3,4,5]
 console.log(a); //[1,2,3]
```

`Array.prototype.slice` will create a copy of the original array when the start value passed along is `0`. But if you are really concerned about passing a hard coded value, use the `call`'s variant.

```
var b= [].slice.call(a);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk a bit about **memory** ...

`a` is saved in memory, for example, at the address of `123`

when you tell in your code to make `b = a`  it just refer to the same `a` at the address `123` so they both have the same place in memory so when you change any of them you change the other
... So what you can do is to create another place in memory for your second array by one of these methods

`var b= a.slice(0);`

**or**

`var b= JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(a));`

**or**

`var b = [].concat(a);`